# How to simulate depth for a group of objects (car rim)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

I'm doing Illustrator artwork of a DeLorean. The DeLorean has two different tire sizes (1" larger diameter rears). The rims have more contour on the rear because of that difference. These are from a model.

[image: Wheels]

I was trying to use "3D and Materials", and I tried messing with the "Perspective" option because when I had outlined some text and experimented on it, it seemed to push it inward like I wanted to. But that option was greyed out. Any other options I've tried messing with, just make the rim look distorted and nothing like it.

[image: Car]

Comment: Typically one would draw various shadows and highlight which simulate depth. i.e. more and darker shadows makes things look deeper. When dealing with 2D vector tools, I don't know that there exists some simple combination of features to merely create depth on a group of objects. Ya can't really "force" things to have a 3D appearance without actually constructing them in a 3D application - which isn't Illustrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, like you want a straight side view. The depth of the rim isn't visible in that direction. Only fine details have glosses and shadows which are different in different parts of the rim. A photo analyzing expert maybe could see the difference of the rim depths if the depth is the only difference.

De Lorean wheels are a popular 3D modelling subject. Some modellers give their creations for free and others want a payment. Here's a link to one example where you can watch it from different directions:

https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/delorean-wheels-813336c9381a4772a8a1ed1e7c6fae42

Check it. A well done 3D model (as properly rendered) is maybe a better information source than a half-descent drawing made by hobbyist or a low resolution photo. Only a real wheel in your hands or manufacturer's drawings are better.